# combine row values in all consecutive rows that contains NaN and int values using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need your help: 
I want to merge consecutive rows like this:

**Input:**

```
Time                      ColA   ColB   Time_for_test[sec]

2020-01-19 08:51:56.461   NaN    B      NaN
2020-01-19 08:52:15.405   NaN    NaN    18.95
2020-01-19 08:52:40.923   A      NaN    NaN
2020-01-19 08:52:59.589   NaN    NaN    18.67
2020-01-19 08:54:07.687   NaN    B      NaN
```

**Output:**

```
Time                      ColA   ColB   Time_for_test[sec]

2020-01-19 08:51:56.461   NaN    B      NaN
2020-01-19 08:52:15.405   NaN    B      18.95
2020-01-19 08:52:40.923   A      NaN    NaN
2020-01-19 08:52:59.589   A      NaN    18.67
2020-01-19 08:54:07.687   NaN    B      NaN
```

Of course, I checked if exist similar cases published on the site:
I tried one adding a new column like that:

```
merge_df = merge_df.fillNa(0)
merge_df['sum'] = merge_df['TableA']+merge_df['Time_for_ST[sec]'].shift(-1)
```

It did not work.

Thank you for patience

Comment: What is the logic here? Do you want `df[['ColA', 'ColB']] = df[['ColA', 'ColB']].ffill(limit=1)`?

Comment: you solution does not change the DataFrame...

Answer (score 0):

`stack` and `unstack` are your friends. Assuming your dataframe index is unique:

```
df[['ColA', 'ColB']].stack() \
    .reset_index(level=1) \
    .reindex(df.index) \
    .ffill() \
    .set_index('level_1', append=True) \
    .unstack() \
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

Since it's one long operation chain, you can run only line 1, then line 1,2, then 1,2,3.... to see how it works.

Comment: Thank you ! you helped me and I succeed to create the DF  I want.